# npm start doesn't start properly

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

In **package.json** I have

```
"scripts": {"start": "node --harmony server.js"}
```

I cd into directory and run `npm start`

```
C:\nodejs\projectname>npm start
<pauses for 3 seconds>
C:\nodejs\projectname>_
```

Prompt pauses for 3 sec, looks like it is processing then it throws me back at blinking cursor prompt

If I manually type:

```
C:\nodejs\projectname>node --harmony server.js
Listening on port 3000
<process running>
```

I browse to localhost:3000 and see a simple Hello World page.

Why is `npm start` having problems and what needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I had two **"scripts: {...}"** defined in two different sections of the **package.json** file. After merging them under one **"scripts: {...}"**:

`"scripts": {"start": "node --harmony server.js", "test": "mocha -R spec"}`

`npm start` works properly now